# Java proper extension design for a class with a generic collection

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I got classes A,B,C such that `B` extends `A` and `C` also extends `A`.

Now I got 2 different classes, lets call them `MyClassB` and `MyClassC` with a member of `ArrayList<B>` and `ArrayList<C>` respectfuly.

Since many actions in `MyClassB` and `MyClassC` are the same and are only done on the different type of ArrayList, I wanted to create a new abstract class `MyClassA` which will have an implementation of the same actions on an `ArrayList<A>` for both classe, since `A` is the common part which the actions are the same on.

So I tried creating a method in the new `MyClassA` class which receives a list as an argument and is supposed to make the action on that list. However, I can't pass an `ArrayList<B>` to the method where it expects `ArrayList<A>`.

So what can I do in order to keep the same actions in a different class and not repeat the code in 2 different classes?

Comment: Use a wildcard, like ?, e.g. ArrayList<? extends A> arr = new ArrayList();

Comment: @avk - covariance may or may not be required here. e.g. sort(ArrayList)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyClassA<T extends A>
{
    ArrayList<T> list;

    public MyClassA(ArrayList<T> list)
    {
        this.list = list;

...

class MyClassB extends MyClassA<B>
{
    MyClassB(ArrayList<B> list)
    {
         super(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with generics:

```
public class MyClassA<T extends A> {
    public void doSomething(ArrayList<T> list) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now `MyClassB` and `MyClassC` can inherit from it and you can work with the list normally.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options: Adding a generic to the base class or work with a wildcard:

```
public final class HolderB extends BaseBase<B>{

@Override
public void abstractAlgo(List<B> elements) { //uses the generic from the base class
  //add Bs
  elements.add(new B());
  //get Bs
  System.out.println(elements.get(0));
}

@Override
public void abstractAlgoWithWildcard(List<? extends Base> elements) { //uses the base class directly
   //add not possible Bs
  elements.add(new B());
  //get Bs
  System.out.println(elements.get(0));
}
```

}

With the wildcard solution its not possible to add new elements to the list, only "read" operations are allowed.